Calculated table with aggregation DAX
Im trying to create a calculated table from 2 tables that are connected with a bridge.
My 3 tables
Report      ReportRow   Account Sign UniqueKey
Rapport129  129/* CM    35100   1    4177960
Rapport129  129/* CM    35100   -1   4174475
Rapport129  129/* CM    34000   1    4176966
Rapport129  129/* CM    93220   -1   4179774

UniqueKey Konto
4179774   93220
4177960   35100
4176966   34000
4174475   35100


FactKey Account Amount
1   35100   10
2   35100   20
3   34000   100
4   34000   200
5   93220   -500
6   93220   300


The Model:

This is how i want my calculated table to look like:


Can you paste  your data as copiable markdown text

Table = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(DimReport, DimReport[Report], DimReport[ReportRow], DimReport[Account]),
    "Sum Sign", CALCULATE( SUM(DimReport[Sign])),
    "Sum Amount", CALCULATE(SUM('Fact'[Amount]))

)

Thank you!! This works great! I realized i wanted to add a column from Date table in this, how do i do that? I have a date table that is connected to Fact and i want to add column Month into this calculated table?

You're best asking a new question with all the details in it

Thanks! I´ve added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78631523/calculated-table-from-2-tables-and-sum-dax

I'll let someone else answer your other question as it doesn't make 100% sense to me
