Calculated table from 2 tables and sum DAX
Im trying to create a calculated table from 2 tables that are connected with a bridge.
My 3 tables
Report      ReportRow   Account Sign UniqueKey
Rapport129  129/* CM    35100   1    4177960
Rapport129  129/* CM    35100   -1   4174475
Rapport129  129/* CM    34000   1    4176966
Rapport129  129/* CM    93220   -1   4179774

UniqueKey Account
4179774   93220
4177960   35100
4176966   34000
4174475   35100


FactKey Account Amount Date
1       35100   10     20240101
2       35100   20     20240101
3       34000   100    20240101
4       34000   200    20240101
5       93220   -500   20240101
6       93220   300    20240101

The Model ( including date table )

This is how i want my calculated table to look like:
Report     ReportRow Account Month Sum(Sign)  Sum(Amount)
Rapport129 129/* CM  35100   1     0          30
Rapport129 129/* CM  34000   1     1          300
Rapport129 129/* CM  93220   1     -1         -200


Why do you need Bridge table if you already have account field in DimReport?

agree, you want to display the account info,However, the account is not unique in the middle table. No need to create this or you only keep the account column and remove duplicates to be a dim table.
